# Crear un filtro de autorizo personalizado en asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#

Estoy creando una aplicación en **Asp.Net Core 2.2** en la que uso tablas personalizadas para realizar la autenticación en mi sistema y mi propia forma de registrar los roles en esta. El hecho está cuando quiero usar el filtro de autorizo `[Authorize(Role="Admin")]` pues no me funciona ya que no tiene forma de determinar si el usuario autenticado tiene dicho rol. Estuve buscando pero no encontré medio alguno para crear un identificador de atributo que me ayudara a sustituir este identificador de autirización.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como has implementado tus propias tablas, una opción sería **crear tu propio atributo/filtro** de autorización que herede de **AuthorizeAttribute** y que se adecúe a tu esquema y lógica. El código sería algo similar al siguiente:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class CustomRoleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private string role;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var service = (IAuthorizationService)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAuthorizationService));

        var roleRequirement = new RoleRequirement(this.role)
        var result = await service.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, null, roleRequirement);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Vas a necesitar una clase que implemente la interfaz **AuthorizationHandler**

```
public class RoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public RoleRequirement(string role)
    {
        this.Role = role;
    }

    public string Role { get; private set; }
}

public class CustomRoleRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
{
    // Usa IoC (inyección de dependencias) para incluir
    // los servicios que necesitas para validar el rol.
    public CustomRequirementHandler ()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        // añade tu lógica aquí, puede ser obtener los roles y usuarios (JOIN) con EF.
        //  o validarlos contra un servicio
        if (requirement.Role ==  "ElRolQueRequieroYQueObtuveDesdeMiLogica")
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

Y con esto ya solo nos queda registrar el servicio en el **startup** de la aplicación

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomRoleRequirementHandler>();
```

Ya luego, solo te queda usarlo en tus controladores.

```
[CustomRoleAuthorizeAttribute("ElRolRequrido")]
```

Comment: Gracias Jesus! sabes como hacer en la vista que esto quede registrado para para poder utilizar como @User.IsInRole("ADMIN") ejemplo?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero por favor ayúdanos a responder preguntas creadas de acuerdo a lo descrito en el Centro de ayuda, específicamente [ask], saludos.